# Are there persons born with more than one quirk aside artificially made creatures?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In My hero academia, Nomu had more than one quirk, but he was made artificially. Are there persons born with  more than one quirk in My Hero Academia or only those who are artificially created can have more than one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's strongly suggested that many of the holders of One For All had a Quirk of their own, with Deku being an exception rather than the norm, but that's a similar process to the one that created Nomu so I don't know if you'd count that.

Other than that, the show doesn't really suggest that having more than one Quirk is something that normally happens, although a single Quirk may have multiple facets (e.g. Todoroki having both ice and fire powers, or the fact that many people have unusual bodies in addition to their Quirks).